# Use a decorator as a wrapper

Tags: python

I have a decorator that I use on a class method. However I would like to use the same decorator but as a wrapper instead.

For instance this is how I use the decorator:

**myDecorators.py**

```
def authenticate(method):
    def authenticate_and_call(service_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Authentification success")
        #access to service_instance is needed in the decorator
        print(service_instance.config)
        return method(service_instance, *args, **kwargs)

    return authenticate_and_call
```

**myClass.py**

```
from myDecorators import authenticate

class MyService:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    @authenticate #I dont want to use a decorator here
    def execute(self):
        print(self.config)
        print("MyService is executed with authentication")
```

What I would like to do is something like:

**service_callers.py**

```
from myClass import MyService
from myDecorators import authenticate

#use the decorator as a wrapper
def execute_service_with_authentification():
    service = MyService({"foo":"bar"})
    authenticate(service.execute)(service)

execute_service_with_authentification()
```

This returns the following error:

```
  File "c:\temp\test\myDecorators.py", line 4, in authenticate_and_call
    return method(service_instance, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: execute() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the `@authenticate` decorator from your `MyService.execute` definiton. Then when you need to use the `authenticate` decorator just wrap your call as: `authenticate(service.execute)()`.

Make sure you change your decorator as well - you're not passing the first argument as self:

```
def authenticate(method):
    def authenticate_and_call(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Attempting authentication on object: {}".format(method.__self__))
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return authenticate_and_call
```

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - remove `service_instance` from your wrapper, just pass the same args/kwargs you give to the wrapper function.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - I've added the changed decorator above. Since we're passing it an instance method it doesn't need the first argument. The above works with your structure, and will work for any arguments you want to pass, too (notice the 'naked' call as it was in my original answer, I wasn't looking at the decorator initially)

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - you don't need an access to it, the method you're passing is already bound to the `service` instance. If you, however, need to do something with it before you actually call the method, you can 'extract' it from its bound method as: `method.__self__`. Check the update above.